# Does Java have a similar post method diamond operator that C# has?

Tags: java, c#, generics

The Unity project makes frequent use of C# functions that supply a type in a diamond operator after the method name.  In the Unity source code it's defined like this:

```
public static T FindObjectOfType<T>() where T : Object
{
    return (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T), false);
}
```

An example of its use:

```
CanvasRenderer canvas = FindObjectOfType<CanvasRenderer>();
```

My question is, does the Java language have a similar construct?

Comment: This is called [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has a similar construct, but the name "diamond operator" is reserved (ok, not really 'reserved', but used) for something slightly different.

In the construct

```java
final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
```

the `<>` is called the "diamond operator" (although "diamond form" would be more correct), and it is a shortcut of the otherwise required term `<String>`.

Defining a method with a generic argument or return type looks in Java slightly different from C#:

```java
public final <T,R> R doSomething( final T argument ) { … }
```

`doSomething()` takes an argument of type `T` and returns a result of type `R`, where `R` and `T` do not need to be distinct from each other.

Calling `doSomething()` may look like this:

```java
final var date = LocalDate.now();
final String result = doSomething( date );
```

Your C# method `FindObjectOfType<T>()` would be declared in Java like this:

```java
public final <T> T findObjectOfType( final Class<T> desiredType ) { … }
```

and it would be called like this:

```java
CanvasRenderer canvas = findObjectOfType( CanvasRenderer.class );
```

Comment: Ah yes, I shouldn't have used the term "Diamond Operator", but it looks like we can only simulate this by passing a class type as a parameter? That's what I thought too but thanks for confirming.

Comment: @NickD – You can also use a 'sample' instance and use `Object::getClass` on it. The reason is that in Java the type argument `T` is not an object instance, it even does not exist during runtime. This means that you cannot use it as an argument for a function call (`typeOf( T )` as in C# will not work …), and it does not have any methods (`T.getClass()` will not work either …).

Answer (score -2):

Yes. These diamond operators are called generics. Java has them too!

They use the same <> syntax. You can find more information online by searching for "java generics"

Comment: Answers that do not attempt to answer the question should be flagged and removed. Downvoting is how [the community indicates which answers are least useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Hey @Izruo, thanks for your reply. I understand those rules and that is why I am confused. The question the op literally asks is "My question is, does the Java language have a similar construct?", Which I answered directly. Again, I didnt think it would be worth providing a tutorial or examples of the syntax because OP/the reader would likely need to find some documentation about it to use it for their own use cases, anyway :)

Comment: You only confirm that Java has generics, not that it has type-parameters on methods (the specific type of generics OP is asking about), and if so what the equivalent syntax is, as such this not a helpful answer.